# Xpages: working with dates in java

Tags: java, xpages

I have a document in Xpages that is managed by an ObjectBean. Binding my fields in the Xpage with EL, so fields look like...

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText2" xp:key="field"
    value="#{ObjectBean.serialNumber}" />
</xp:this.facets>
```

In my bean I have getters,setters,loading, validation and so on and it works fine.

Now I need to add a date field. In the Xpage I have

```
                        <xp:inputText xp:key="field"
                            id="checkInDate" value="#{ObjectBean.checkInDate}">
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime
                                    type="date">
                                </xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:dateTimeHelper>
                            </xp:dateTimeHelper>
                        </xp:inputText>
```

I realize that adding a Date or DateTime field will require some special code, but cannot figure out what to do.

My getters and setters are:

```
public Date getCheckInDate() {      
        if (checkInDate == null) {
            checkInDate = new Date();
        }
        return checkInDate;
}

public void setCheckInDate(Date checkInDate) {
    this.checkInDate = checkInDate;
}
```

In my save I am trying this

Date tmpDate = session.createDateTime(checkInDate).toJavaDate();
doc.replaceItemValue("checkInDate",checkInDate);

and this

```
doc.replaceItemValue("checkInDate",session.createDateTime(checkInDate));
```

but I either get an error, or in the second case I don't get an error but nothing is saved (the doc is not saved).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a Date as parameter to the method createDateTime, but in the documentation is stated it should be a String.

You need to convert Date to a String, see http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Or use OpenNTF Domino API, replaceItemValue will also accept a Date ;-)